# Why MediaPlayer can still work even after the tread finishes?

Tags: android, multithreading

I start the mediaplayer to play a piece of music in a thread and I'm wondering why mediaplayer can continue working even the thread is already dead. Here is the example:

```
public class MusicThread extends Thread {
    MediaPlayer mp;
    public MusicThread(Context context) {
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.music);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        mp.start();
        Log.d("MusicThread", "mp started");
    }
}
```

Then inside the activity:

```
MusicThread musicThread = new MusicThread(this);
musicThread.start();
```

Here is my confusion:

After `musicThread.start()`, the music begins. Also, the thread completes becasue we can see the log generated by `Log.d(...)` in `LogCat` and we can see the `false` returned by `musicThread.isAlive()`.

I have the reference to `musicThread` such that it won't be GC immediately when it  finishes.

But what about the mediaplayer? It continues working but the thread which it resides has died already. It seems that it's in a weird state in this case. Is it still working in `musicThread`? If yes, why and how? If not, where it is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mp.start()` is not a blocking call. So your thread won't wait until playing is finished. `mp.start()` call returns immediately. You don't even need a separate thread to call it.

PS : If you want to get a callback when the playing is finished just use setOnCompletionListener. Once the playing is completed, `public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp)` will be called

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! May I know where you find that mp.start() is not a synchronous call? I looked into the documentation but did not find statements like that. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @xwb1989 : Actually `start()` IS a synchronous method although it is not a 'blocking' method. I think Shashika's wording is misleading. The `start()` method will return without blocking the calling thread but `MediaPlayer` uses its own thread for playback.

Comment: Yes in the documentation it's not clearly stated. But in here http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html#preparingasync it says "never call prepare() from your application's UI thread". Once the mediaplayer is prepared we can start it even within the UI thread.

Comment: thanks @Squonk for the correction. I have edited my answer. What I meant was its not a blocking method. Sorry for the wrong wording.

Comment: @Squonk and Shashika Thanks very much for the detailed explanation!